# Sphinx NEAR and << issues

Tags: sphinx

I'm looking for a pattern where Word 1 is near AND before Word 2. So my basic query was like

```
(Word1 << Word 2) (Word1 NEAR\2 Word2)
```

Which will naturally match

- bla bla **Word1 Word2**
- bla bla **Word1** and **Word2**

but not match

- bla bla Word2 Word1
- bla bla Word1 bla bla. Bla bla bla. Word2 bla bla.

The problem is it DOES match

- bla bla **Word1**.  Bla bla bla **Word2** Word1.

is that matches both the NEAR/1 and the << conditions though not in the way I intended.

Is there any other operator/logic I can use to negate the match in the last example?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think is

```
"Word1 word2" | "word1 * word2"
```